# ddf standard xml format returns no records

Tags: php, xml, rets

I am using the code below to query the CREA DDF/RETS to retrieve listings in the XML format. When I specify the Standard-XML format, I get no records with no errors.

If I do not specify the format, PHRETS defaults to Compact-Decoded format and records are returned.

code

```
require('phrets.php');
$rets = new phRETS;

$criteria = 'LastUpdated=2012-01-01';
$limit = 10;
$options = array('Limit' => $limit, 'Format' => 'Standard-XML'); # also tried STANDARD-XML - wasn't sure if it was case sensitive
$search = $rets->SearchQuery('Property', 'Property', $criteria, $options);
$total_records = $rets->TotalRecordsFound();
$error_info = $rets->Error();

echo "error (code {$error_info['code']}): {$error_info['text']}\n";
echo $total_records." - total_records\n";

$rets->FreeResult($search);
$rets->Disconnect();
```

results

error (code ):

0 - total_records

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Since I'm new to the whole DDF/RETS, is there something I'm missing, doing wrong or try different that someone with more experience would have been through or can point out? I figure it should work since the only thing I'm changing is the format, and I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Try capitalizing 'Standard-XML' in your options array. In your search query, you have "SearchQuery('Property','Property')". Are you sure that's correct? Usually it's something like "SearchQuery('Property','RES')", where the second parameter is the class of Property like residential, commercial, or land.

Comment: I tried all uppercase before posting - no luck. Property is the correct class with the DDF/RETS. It works when I don't use Standard-XML as the format. Thanks though.

Comment: You may have to use a CREA-specific version of PHRETS as CREA is not an entirely RETS 1.7.2 server. It also requires the use of STANDARD-XML, which PHRETS does not wholly support, even in version 2.1. https://github.com/tehraven/PHRetsForCREA/blob/master/PHRets_CREA.php

Answer (score 0):

Your Rets search query is not proper.

If you would like to get property which updated after 2012-01-01,
Corrected search query:

```
$criteria = '(LastUpdated=2012-01-01+)';
```

If this search query is not working then try like

```
$criteria = '(LastUpdated=2012-01-01%2B)';
```

because some rets server have encoding related issue. '%2B' is url encoded format of'+' sign.

If you would like to get property which updated at 2012-01-01,
Search query:

```
$criteria = '(LastUpdated=2012-01-01)';
```